# How to seperate sidebar and content?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to make a side bar and a content div but I don't know how to keep them separated and the content goes under the sidebar and obviously I don't want that. I'm pretty new to coding so I don't know what to do or if there's a better way to do this.

[image: picture]
Here's the code:

```
<div id="content" style="margin:50px; background-color:blue; padding:10px;">
   <div id="sidebar" style="margin:25px; background-color:red; width:200px; border: 2px solid lime; position:fixed;">
      <p>h</p>
   </div>
   <div id="stuff" style="background-color:orange; margin:20px;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post code as text. This makes it easier for other users so you are more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: my bad. i'll update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` at top level. It's easier to use than `position: fixed` or any other positioning strategies.

```css
#content {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

#content #sidebar {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
}

#content #stuff {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar" style="">
    <p>h</p>
  </div>
  <div id="stuff" style="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position:fixed` do `position:relative` for the sidebar. This will prevent the text from going under the sidebar.
If you want the sidebar to occupy the full width of the parent container you could do `height: 100%`.

I would also suggest that you keep the style and html separated. Either inside a `<script></script>` tag or in another file.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: fixed`. This property is used to position an element at a particular location on the browser window, yet you are not providing any position properties to support it.

Add `display: inline-block` css properties to the *sidebar* and *stuff* divs if you want to allow the content of the other div to wrap around the sidebar.